# Best practices for open sourcing iOS app?

Tags: xcode, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I am considering making the git repos for an iOS app open source. Is there any information in the `.pbxproj` or similar files I should keep secret or avoid contributing to the repo?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Xcode.gitignore (and many others readily available)

Comment: I think it's ok to just open source it. The team identifier (which I think is the only thing that might be sensitive) won't show your real name (ex. John Smith), instead, will show YS23JSD87 or something.

Comment: Thanks @matt! Also, good to know about the team identifier @aheze